# Unity - Vertical/Grid layout group

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, ui

Имеется scrollView.В Content этого scrollView спавнятся префабы(ItemShop - первый скрин).
На Content я повесил Vertical layout group(Второй скрин).Надеюсь,что я правильно понял и Control Child Size - растягивает дочерние объекты по ширине родителя.
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как сделать,чтобы дочерние элементы имели ширину равную Content.На третьем скрине видно,что дочерние объекты намного шире чем сам родитель.

*Префабы у меня спавнятся в начале игры и ширину они имеют не как у родителя.Но,если я добавляю те же префабы до запуска игры,то они выглядят нормально,но,к сожалению,у меня логика игры, что нужно именно спавнить префабы,а переделывать нет возможности.*

***Спасибо.***

[image: ItemShop префаб]

[image: Content]

[image: Item]

Comment: Ты так обрезал скриншоты что на них не видно самого главного.

Comment: Не понял,а что есть главное?

Comment: В этом и прикол, ты обрезал, не имея представления что может быть важным.